# Will My Schnauzer Accept a New Puppy

Tags: new-pets

I have an intact, male miniature Schnauzer not quite 2 years old.  He is very friendly with people, and generally likes other dogs (though we have had mounting issues).  I plan on getting another male mini Schnauzer in the near future.  Are mini Schnauzers generally accepting of new puppies?  Is there anything I can do to help him adapt?

Comment: Have a look into this question about introducing two male dogs and the linked one there about neutering-helpful or not: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/how-can-i-introduce-my-puppy-to-my-boyfriends-dogs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I introduce my puppy to my boyfriend's dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/how-can-i-introduce-my-puppy-to-my-boyfriends-dogs)

Comment: No, it was not.

Comment: *anecdotally* , with a sample size of 2 dogs I know of, Schnauzers tend to actually do really well with other Schnauzer puppies. Their reactions to other breeds may vary. I also found that dogs of 'different' ages seem to get along better, regardless of breed.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, the older puppy was never aggressive toward the new puppy.  It took a little bit of time for him to get used to his new brother, but after about a week they are big buddies.  It was a great choice for me, because 2 dogs can keep one another entertained, and lets me do my work-from-home without feeling bad about not playing with my dog.

Comment: Did you see the "alternatives to walking a dog" question? It has many interesting activities you can do with your dogs. Also some you can prepare and they can enjoy on their own when you need to work.